# How to Validate Your Position Arrived on Tasked Latitude and Longitude on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

I'm on my way making tracking apps with some task point, but i got problem to validate and make expression to validate the position with the task position, i store the position on database by latitude and longitude point, but it can't be possible that i compare 100% exact same position value with the tasked position lat and long right? because i think we need some tolerance for the positioning validation. so the question is simply almost same like how google maps count we arrived on our destination? im using php, javascript google maps API. Thanks for your help

Comment: Simple. Calculate [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between two positions (task & current). If distance lower than some threshold - we arrived at destination

Comment: make sense bro. im on it. THANKS BIG BIG THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ans of this question in coding is almost impossible but i am trying to explain you how google works and to accomplish this you need tons of data with heavy servers and few satellite
how google determine our locations.
When you search for directions using Google Maps, there are a variety of factors at play in determining when you'll actually arrive, according to a former Google engineer.In a post on Quora recently spotted by 9to5Mac, ex-Google engineer Richard Russell reveals more of what that is:"Like in similar products, Google maps ETAs are based on a variety of things, depending on the data available in a particular area. These things range from official speed limits and recommended speeds, likely speeds derived from road types, historical average speed data over certain time periods (sometimes just averages, sometimes at particular times of day), actual travel times from previous users, and real-time traffic information. They mix data from whichever sources they have, and come up with the best prediction they can make.

Most companies who do live traffic compare their predictions against actual time in traffic to tune their algorithms and data sources. The likely result of this is that the companies who have access to the best usage data (ie those who are best able to compare their predictions against reality, which means those who have the most usage) are likely to end up with the best predictions in the medium to long term."

In short, there's a ton of data Google is calculating just to tell you that your destination may happen to be 10 minutes away. The company also revealed more on how crowdsourced traffic data helps make Maps even more accurate in 2009.

"When we combine your speed with the speed of other phones on the road, across thousands of phones moving around a city at any given time, we can get a pretty good picture of live traffic conditions," wrote Dave Barth, product manager for Google Maps.

Of course, no matter how much data is involved, the time you get will likely never be perfect. As Russell writes, calculating ETAs "is a future-prediction problem, and traffic, while it follows certain patterns, is inherently unpredictable."

Google may know a ton of information, but it doesn't know about the car crash that may have just happened or the school bus making multiple stops in front of you.

The shortest way to get the destination is that get the destination and save it in database and use google map api (autocomplete) it will watch destination which you have in your website for more detail click on autocomplete. here is link [google map api autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete)

i hope it will help you

Comment: thanks bud for the explanation it helped. big big thanks

Comment: you are welcome if you are satisfy with the ans you can click on tick mark thanks